# Use inverse function theorem to evaluate $d/dx \arcsin(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Use inverse function theorem to evaluate $d/dx \arcsin(x)$.

How is this any different then finding it using implicit differentiation? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the theorem that gives the derivative of the inverse of $f$ in terms of $f$? It's different in that you are just using  a formula to obtain the derivative. Of course, the second step when using implicit differentiation brings you that formula.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment I'll assume that by the "inverse function theorem" you mean
$$
\frac{d}{dx} f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}.
$$

Let's see:
$$
\begin{align}
y & = f^{-1}(x) \\  \\
f(y) & = x \\  \\
\frac{d}{dx} f(y) & = \frac{d}{dx} x = 1\tag{implicit differentiation} \\  \\
f'(y) \frac{dy}{dx} & = 1 \\  \\
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{1}{f'(y)} = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}.
\end{align}
$$

This uses implicit differentiation to prove the implicit function theorem.

So one answer to "What's the difference?" is that if you're to use the theorem, you just use the *conclusion* without writing the derivation, whereas if you're to use implicit differentiation, then you're writing out the derivation.  But probably the latter means you're to apply it to a particular concrete case rather than writing something like what appears above, where $f$ could be any function at all rather than some specified particular one.